# is node.js compatible with elementary loki?

Tags: release-loki

I try to install it with Linuxbrew. Then, it stuck at `make install`. I try to leave it about 20 minutes and still no change. Am I being impatient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no troubles installing NodeJS with Linuxbrew, I suppose you install Linuxbrew following the instructions in the [offical page](http://linuxbrew.sh/). And later just install with:

```
brew install node
```

In my case, installation took 19 minutes 26 seconds but everything was fine.

Comment: I think there is some Dependencies I forget to install. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can install NodeJS this way :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo node -v && npm -v
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed with with `apt install` just fine and can run servers and everything. I don't have experience with linuxbrew though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using eOS Loki too and I updated nodejs too, these are my simple steps that you can follow :

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

You can check version of your nodejs with:

```
node -v

v6.10.2
```